# Start the index from zero

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble in this program, which is written to convert Unicode characters to 32-bit format; in the index section that started from zero.
Does the index need to start from zero?

Why can not it start from number 1? Please explain this part well.

```
int a;
textBox2.Text = " ";
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
{
    a = Char.ConvertToUtf32(textBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1), 0);
    textBox2.Text = a.ToString();
    if (textBox1.Text == " ")
    {
        textBox2.Text = " " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because indices in String are from `0` to `size - 1`?

Comment: Because that's how the .Net framework was designed. The index in **any** collection that is built in the framework (and yes, `string` is actually a collection) is zero based, meaning it starts at `0` and ends at `size - 1`.

Comment: Also, [Understanding how zero-based indexing works is the secret handshake of the programming world.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/03/16/zero-or-one-based-collection/) We all started not knowing the secret handshake, but over time we learned and even began to like the secret handshake, and now we don't know any other way to shake hands.

Answer (score 0):

A string is similar to an array, and indexes in c# start from 0 for any array type. As for your code's efficiency, you can also move the if check inside the loop, to outside, as it is independent of any index. See the sample code  below:

```
/// <param name="source"> equivalent to TextBox1.Text in original post</param>
public static int[] ConvertToUtf32(string source)
{
    int[] result = new int[source.Length]; //equivalent to all the chars displayed in TextBox2.Text in original post

    if (source.Equals(" "))
    {
        result[0] = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Char.ConvertToUtf32(source.Substring(i, 1), 0);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```